# Printing a general tree in tree format

Tags: c++, printing, tree

I have created a **general tree** and i need a function to print it in its tree format in c++. I am able to print a binary tree in which the amount of spaces for a given level is fixed but a general tree can have any number of nodes in a particular level so how do i calculate the spaces required.
This is the code I created for a binary tree.

```
void prnttree(node* p,int a)
//a contains the value of maximum Height
{
    int ht=0;
        int i,c=0;
    node* n=NULL;
    end=0;
    start=0;
    q[end]=p;
    do
    {
        if(p!=NULL)
        {
                        //q is an array of pointers to node   
            q[++end]=p->left;
            q[++end]=p->right;
        }
        else
        {
            q[++end]=n;
            q[++end]=n;
        }
        if(pow(2,ht)-1==c)
        {
            cout<<"\n\n";
            for(i=1;i<=(pow(2,a-ht+1)-2);i++)
                cout<<" ";
        }
        if(p!=NULL)
            cout<<p->data;
        else
                cout<<" ";
        for(i=1;i<=(pow(2,a-ht+2)-1);i++)
            cout<<" ";
        p=q[++start];
        c++;
        if(c+1==pow(2,ht+1))
            ht++;
    }while(ht<=a);
}
```

Comment: What is a general tree?

Comment: do you want to print it as it should come like an actual representation. like the real tree type structure??

Comment: Ya, the child nodes should be below the parent. Something like this but need not have lines and stuff. [http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/img148.gif ]

Comment: general tree is just a tree, a node can have any number of children.

Comment: atleast you must be having a maximum number of child nodes a parent  can have?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first find the maximum height of the given tree and use the below helper function to print each level of the given tree.

```
void prnttreeHelper(node* p)
{
    int maxHeight = findHeight(p);
    for(int i = 0;i<height;i++)
    {
        //formula to print initial number of spaces for the tree like structure
        //which will be dependant on the max allowed child nodes and the height of tree
        prnttree(p,i,0);
        cout<<'\n';
    }
}
```

And you actual function goes like

```
void prnttree(node* root, int currLevel, int lvlPrint)
{
    if(p==null)
    {
        cout<<'\t';
        return;
    }
    if(currLevel == lvlPrint)
        cout<<p->data<<'\t';
    else
    {
        prnttree(root->child[0], currLevel, lvlPrint+1);
        prnttree(root->child[1], currLevel, lvlPrint+1);
        //..for n number of possible child(considering a parent can have a max of n children
    }
}
```

This is the correct way of printing the child below tha parent but the spacing part will have to be worked out based on the maximum number of child nodes a parent can have.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this is not how i have implemented the tree, a single node has the following links, father, son(just 1) and sibling, i implemented in this way becoz then a node can have any number of children and not limited by a max number. Can u think of something for this . A node has only 1 son and any number of siblings

Comment: @VinithVenkatesan How would one know your tree implementation without seeing it. Please write the structure of your tree as well in the question. Also are you planning to use vectors for `any number of siblings` as without that you cannot do it. I would strongly suggest you to consider your structure again and change it to one I have assumed

Comment: I am srry for not being clear, my tree structure is: a single node has only 1 child and its other children are connected as siblings to that 1st child. so its like a single linked list in the level of the son. for example if a node has 10 children, then the parent node has 1 son and that son is linked to 1st sibling and that 1st sibling has a sibling link to the 2nd sibling and 2nd to 3rd and so on. so in this way a single node can have any number of children by creating it when needed.